# Call WebMethod using jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, web-services

Hi i want to pass the values from jQuery and assign those values to a class model which is used in a method.

Following is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#BtnSubmit').click(function () {
            var CollegeName = $('#TxtCollegeName').val();
            var CollegeAddress = $('#TxtCollegeAddress').val();
            var pageUrl = '<%=ResolveUrl("~/AddNewCollege.aspx/CreateCollegeData")%>';
            $.ajax({
                type: 'Post',
                url: pageUrl,
                data: JSON.stringify({ "CollegeName": CollegeName, "CollegeAddress": CollegeAddress}),
                dataType: 'text',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#lblResult').html('Inserted Successfully');                        
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("An error occurred.");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Below is my Csharp method:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string CreateCollegeData(CollegeDetails collegeDetails)
    {
        CollegeDAL obj = new CollegeDAL();
        bool b = obj.InsertCollegeDetails(collegeDetails);
        return "success";
    }
```

But debugger is unable to call the web method. Every time the following message is coming:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try declaring your object ahead of time: [link](http://encosia.com/using-complex-types-to-make-calling-services-less-complex/)

Comment: Mid-way down the page under "Cleaning up the client-side" is a good way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I got another solution.

```
 $('#BtnSubmit').click(function () {
            var collegeDetails = {};
            collegeDetails.CollegeName = $('#TxtCollegeName').val();
            collegeDetails.CollegeAddress = $('#TxtCollegeAddress').val();               
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'AddNewCollege.aspx/CreateCollegeData',
                data: "{collegeDetails:" + JSON.stringify(collegeDetails) + "}",
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#lblResult').html('Inserted Successfully');
                    $('#TxtCollegeName').val('');
                    $('#TxtCollegeAddress').val('');
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("An error occurred.");
                }
            });
        });
```